# Can this 274k+ view question get a wikilock please?

Tags: support, specific-question, locked-posts

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

This is a really, really bad, unsolvable question that has managed to accumulate over a quarter million views in two short years. However, the one answer it has is excellent. It has a delete vote on it.

The answers have made a good point that, because there's no controversy, why freeze it in time?

However, it seems like it's got one canonical answer for lots of different scenarios; can it be Wikilocked please?

Comment: There's no history of close/reopen battles, never been deleted, and 33 upvotes means it will take more than 3 delete votes to actually delete it.  Doesn't seem to be an ideal candidate for a historical lock at the moment.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think it will take 8 delete votes, 33 + 78 = 111 / 20 = 5 + 3 = 8

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for the math and couldn't remember where to find it.... but the number of delete votes needed is the point.  Why completely lock a question so it can't be edited, updated, voted on, or otherwise maintained because of a single delete vote when you need 7 more to actually delete it

Comment: 274K views. At a question that was closed [two years ago, in the day of posting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18060667/revisions). This suggests that despite closure, it did something right and we better invest some effort into maintaining it

Comment: Interestingly, the user who posted this question was last seen on the same day as the question was posted. All the badges for this user are from this question (except the yearling badge, which i fail to understand. how can a person last seen 2 years back be awarded yearling badge just 1 hour ago?)

Comment: Not every day you see such a highly-upvoted answer from someone who goes to the same school I went to. This is in spite of the fact that it was written and formatted *very* differently from how it appears today.

Comment: @BoltClock And who just got a gold badge for it. Probably because of this MSO question ;)

Comment: @durron597: Given that our country's celebrating 50 years this weekend, I feel like I'm channeling my inner patriot already.

Comment: What is a wikilock?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think this question can be made on topic with a little tweak.

Considering it's getting lots of hits, and the best answer has debugging steps for the exception, I think this can be brought on topic by following [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) as a guide. This question doesn't tell you why your code threw a NRE, but it tells you how to debug that exception.

I've edited the question to ask for debugging tips for this exception rather than asking for guesses as to what is the actual reason.

Comment: I've edited it myself, but it's still too broad, no? Perhaps it should be wikilocked, so others can revise/improve the answer.

Comment: @durron597 not really too broad.  Close, but no.  Look at the NRE question I linked--it's exactly the same.  There are LOADS of reasons why the exception can be thrown, and everyone's situation is different.  The answer details HOW you debug the exception.  There is a finite number of ways this can be done.  The question then becomes a canonical dupe for all similar vague questions about the same error.  You can close them all as dupes.

Comment: @Bill Woodger: It's not meant to be one's "own solution", but a collection of various troubleshooting techniques for different scenarios all leading to the same error. That's fine, as long as all the sources are properly cited.

Comment: @Bill Woodger: Yeah I see where you're coming from. Also, "See More At" is basically the same "More Info:" nonsense that people pull instead of outright stating that the link is the source of the copied text (though in this case the user did include a References section at the end of their answer). I've never understood why people did that. Lemme give that answer a little massage...

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks. Tidying away.

Answer (score 13):

The question has been closed once and never reopened.

It has not been deleted ever, let alone gone through a deletion/undeletion cycle.

Given that, there's no need to apply a historical lock here.

If, in the future, it ends up getting deleted, or reopened, or in particular if either of those happens and the post starts cycling back into it's current state, *then* a historical lock can be considered.

A *single* delete vote isn't really enough to indicate considerable disagreement or controversy among users that would necessitate a lock.